# I've just discovered that "spuriative" isn't a real word. What word am I mistaking this for?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I've just discovered that "spuriative" doesn't exist in English, despite having quite a firm definition for it in my head. I've even used this word in spoken conversation to many English speakers and they've understood my meaning from the given context. I have no idea when this might have started, or where I could have heard it initially.

I can't find any suggested alternative spellings or related usages of this word whatsoever. Where might I have got this from, and what real English word could I substitute?

Here's my best definition for "spuriation":

> **Spuriation** /ˈspjʊərieɪʃən/ 
> To form a future forecast, prediction, or guess based on best case scenarios and very little factual foundation. Generally positive in outlook or naive in nature.

For example:

> *Spuriative investment had caused the company to balloon in value, even though it hadn't yet made any sales.*

The closest match I can think of is "speculation" but that doesn't feel like it hits the right note. Spuriation is more specifically projecting forwards your hopeful or unfounded beliefs of things turning out well or successful.

Comment: To me, it sounds like a combination of *spurious* and *speculative*, which fits your meaning pretty well. But I can't think of any close real word.

Comment: See [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau). Though I think yours is a neologism.

Comment: Wouldn't a new portmanteau also be a neologism?

Comment: Your word might be *spurious* (rhymes with *curious*). Brief definition: (of a line of reasoning) apparently but not actually valid.

Comment: [**Pipe dream**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pipe-dream)

Comment: Why did you make up a definition for **spuriation** when you're asking about **spuriative**?